# Using Flyway application integration with Pax Exam to test OSGi application

Tags: java, osgi, flyway, pax-exam

When trying to use [Flyway application integration](https://code.google.com/p/flyway/wiki/ApplicationIntegration) to test an OSGi application using [Pax Exam](http://team.ops4j.org/wiki/display/paxexam/Pax+Exam), I get the following error:

```
myTest:myTest.myTest:PaxRunnerTestContainer{felix}(com.example.sys.test.paxtests.myTest): 
javax.sql.DataSource not found by com.googlecode.flyway.core [32]
```

When I instantiate a new Flyway

```
Flyway flyway = new Flyway();
```

I am provisioning Flyway and javax.sql thusly:

```
return provision(
...
wrappedBundle("http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven2/javax/sql/jdbc-stdext/2.0/jdbc-stdext-2.0-sources.jar"),
wrappedBundle(mavenBundle().groupId("com.googlecode.flyway").artifactId("flyway-core").version("1.5")),
...
);
```

Is there a proper way to do this so that Flyway is aware of `javax.sql`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been reported here: https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/118
Feel free to star it. :-)

I'll look into fixing this and adding a proper integration test for OSGi environments to the Flyway build in time for the next release.

Comment: Thanks, Axel.  Enjoying Flyway.